# question about finding a more efficient jquery css selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a wrapper div containing  10 thumbnail divs each of which contains 10 img tags, I want an array of the first img tag's of each of these 10 thumbnail divs. Currently I am doing

```
$('#wrapper').find('.thumbnail').find('img:first') //--> [<img>, <img>, ... , <img>] 10 img tags total
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#wrapper .thumbnail > img:first-child')
```

Comment: Ah, forget my answer...this is better. :) I was going to suggest this one, when I saw Nik's comment about only the first img being returned. I didn't realized the difference between the first-child and first selectors..

Comment: This one did it! Thanks NeXXeus

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this `$('#wrapper .thumbnail img:first-child')`

Comment: Thanks CarlosZ, but that returns only 1 img tag

Comment: Yes it is, make it first-child, and it should be working properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aidiakapi, I just fixed it.

Comment: So does this differ from the answer from NeXXeus in that if I wrapped EACH of those img tag with, say, a div tag, this selector will still find what I want?

Comment: by using the `#parent > .child` selector you will only get the first-level descendants of `#parent` not using the `>` will allow to get all children with the `.child` class, regardless of whether they are first level.

Comment: @CarlosZ, but in the example he described, this image will always be the first descendant, so I doubt that you actually NEED to use the `>` operator. Still you're right, the `>` operator retrieves the direct descendants, not descendants of descendants. Anyways, I'll +1 you, cause you fixed it ;).